# Python - Can't reproduce console output in a file form

Tags: python-3.5

I'm very new to Python, with no previous experience in programming, so if my questions seem stupid, that's because they are.
I was trying to lean a bit more about the "requests" library, so I installed it and followed the instructions in this page (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/). When I got to "Response Content", I tried to emulate the code by copying and pasting it, creating a file named pedidos.py, and running it on my terminal. But when I run it, nothing happens.
This is the code as I copied it:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
r.text
```

The strangest thing is, if I open a python console in my terminal and input this code line by line, I get a output, which doesn't happen if run it through the file.

I'm fairly certain that the answer to my question is, probably, very simple, and that I will be ashamed to have asked it once someone explains it to me. But the truth is that I'm stuck and really need some help.

Thanks in advance to anyone who takes the time to answer.

Comment: Try changing `r.text` to `print(r.text)`

Comment: Thanks Jon, that was enough. I was so respectful of what was written in the documentation that I switched off my brain.